# TeXShop only inserts first 60 photos of 70 in book

Tags: floats

Preparing book with 70 images and only first 60 are put in. Using graphicx.

Calling files:

```
\addphoto{IMG_6977.jpg}
\addphoto{IMG_4494.jpg}
\addphoto{m - 159.jpg}
\addphoto{IMG_0853.jpg}
\addphoto{IMG_3386.jpg}
\addphoto{m - 40.jpg}
\addphoto{IMG_3529.jpg}
\addphoto{IMG_7007.jpg}. <- Error occurs before this file (#61), no photos past here
\addphoto{m - 138.jpg}
\addphoto{IMG_0815.jpg}
\addphoto{m - 74.jpg}
```

Top of .tex file:

```
% Designed to run under "pdfLaTeX + BibTeX + MakeIndex" option in TeXworks
\documentclass[openright,twoside,12pt]{book}
% Page Setup:
    \usepackage[
    paperwidth=8.5in,
    paperheight=8.5in,
    bindingoffset=0.2in,
    left=1.25in,
    right=1.25in,
    top=1.25in,
    bottom=1.11in,
    includefoot
    ]{geometry}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}
% Header/Footer Page Numbering and color:
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhf{}
    \setlength{\footskip}{45pt}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\textcolor{gray}{\thepage}}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
% Path to graphics files (add if not in same subdirectory as master .tex file:
    \graphicspath{ {images/} }
%\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.1}
% Insert Graphic on a single page with vspace and scaling:
    \newcommand{\addphoto}[1]{
\begin{figure}
    \vspace*{-.8cm}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6.in]{#1}
\end{figure}
    }
```

Comment: I'd use `\begin{figure}[htbp]` inside `\addphoto` and since you have so many floats in a row might be useful to run `\clearpage` once in a while. I would have thought you'd get an error or warning about this.

Comment: There is no point in using `figure` here replace `\begin{figure}
    \vspace*{-.8cm}
    \centering` by `\begin{center}` and `\end{figure}` by `\end{center}`  Note texshop is just the editor you used to write teh file it is not involved here

Comment: If you want help with an error message you should say what the error is. if it's about too many floats you could use `\extrafloats{100}` to allow more but better would not be to use floats at all.

Comment: I don't know TeX, but noticed that the offending line has a full-stop after the closing brace... if that's not been accidentally added while adding "`<- Error occurs...`", could that be the problem?

Comment: TripeHound, that is just typo pasting in I guess. Adding \extrafloats and using \clearpage seem to be the easiest ways to get what I want. thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you want help with an error message you should say what the error is. if it's about `too many floats` you could use

```
 \extrafloats{100}
```

to allow more but better would not be to use floats at all.

There is no point in using `figure` here as you do not want the pictures to float. Replace

```
\begin{figure}
\vspace*{-.8cm}
\centering
```

by

```
\begin{center}
```

and

```
\end{figure}
```

by

```
\end{center}
```

Comment: thanks David! That inserts all photos, but now the vspace doesn't work and the images are too high on the page. How do I add some space on the top?  '''\begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width=6.in]{#1}
\end{center}

Comment: you could use `\begin{center}\vspace*{...`  if you want a space that is not discarded on a new page